# AWS ElasticSearch without Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am developing log system for turn-based mobile game and I wonder about the pros and cons, if I use only Lambda function without Kinesis between the client app and ElasticSearch to push logs into.

The logs would be actions like touch, sweep and billing information and so on. Since I'm a newbie with AWS serverless services, any kinds of words will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of logs file? Realtime monitor or just for history tracibility?

Comment: @BTuan Both of them. We will use the logs in the realtime when we open a daily event but most of the time we gonna use them as a statistical purpose.

Comment: Its good to use Kinesis for both realtime checking and statistic. Kinesis is ready to create query and get result from existing log data. If you use ElasticSearch, you need to implement some function to query needed data, then need something to virtualize these data. So I refer to use Kinesis with out of the box function. But at this moment Kinesis Analytics just supports 3 regions.

Comment: @BTuan If I have to write Lambda function to query data from Kinesis to ElasticSearch, why can't I use just Lambda function? I think the cost will get reduced. What is the benefit of Kinesis for the cost?

Comment: no, if you use Kinesis, no need to use Lambda or ElastiCache. You can stream your data into Kinesis Stream, then use SQL to query data with Kinesis Analytics, also create dashboards. If you store data in ElastiCache, you need to implement some other services like Lambda function to query data in ElastiCache, then show it in somewhere. That's why Kinesis is the best solution in this case.

Comment: @BTuan ElastiCache? I didn't mention about that. Do you mean, if I use Kinesis + Kinesis Anlytics, in that case I don't need to use Lambda function with the extra cost, however if I use Kinesis + ElasticSearch, in that case I have to use Lambda function?

Comment: sr Its typo. I mean ElasticSearch.

Comment: I see, thank you for the replies @BTuan.